# pipe : write to front of pipe

Tags: c, linux, pipe

I came across `TIMM_OSAL_WriteToFrontOfPipe` and `TIMM_OSAL_WriteToPipe` in the [link](http://security.nknu.edu.tw/AOSP/Android6/hardware/ti/omap4-aah/domx/mm_osal/src/timm_osal_pipes.c)

In `TIMM_OSAL_WriteToPipe` looks like, data is simply written to write end of pipe. 
where as,
In `TIMM_OSAL_WriteToFrontOfPipe`, data is written at the write end, then again read and again written.

I tried to reproduce the same using a sample program below. But could not understand the point of reading and writing again. Could someone please throw some light on it ?

```
int main(void)
{
int fd[2];

int status = pipe (fd);
if (status) {
    fprintf(stderr, "** pipe create failed");
    return 0;
}

status = fork();
if (status < 0)
    fprintf (stderr, "** fork failure!");

if (status == 0){
    //close (fd[1]);
    char buf[5] = {0,};
    int ret_size;
    fprintf(stderr, "child going to sleep...\n");
    sleep (10);
    fprintf(stderr, "\nchild woken up...\n");
    ret_size = read (fd[0], buf, 5);
    fprintf (stderr, "child printing ...\n");
    fprintf (stderr, "%s\n", buf);
} else {
    char buf[5] = {0};
    int read_sz;
    int write_sz;
    //close (fd[0]);
    strcpy(buf,"1");
    write_sz = write (fd[1], buf, 1);
    strcpy(buf,"2");
    write_sz = write (fd[1], buf, 1);
    strcpy(buf,"3");
            write_sz = write (fd[1], buf, 1);
    strcpy(buf,"4");
    write_sz = write (fd[1], buf, 1);
    if (write_sz < 0)
        fprintf (stderr, "write failed");
    else
        fprintf(stderr, "written 1234\n");

    memset(buf, 0, sizeof(buf));

    strcpy(buf,"5");
    write(fd[1], buf, 1);

    memset(buf, 0, sizeof(buf));

    read_sz =  read (fd[0], buf, 5);
    if (read_sz > 0)
        fprintf(stderr, "read data :\n%s\n", buf);

    //write back to pipe
    write (fd[1], buf, 5);

}
return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
written 1234
read data :
12345
child going to sleep...
child woken up...
child printing ...
12345
```

I also tried by not `fork`ing and reading and writing in the same process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WriteToFrontOfPipe means:

`|----------------CURRENT_DATA| -> |------CURRENT_DATA YOUR_DATA|`

Because pipe acts like queue, it takes 3 operations:

`|------YOUR_DATA CURRENT_DATA|` // write your data

`|-------------------YOUR_DATA|` // read tail to put your data in front

`|------CURRENT_DATA YOUR_DATA|` // save previous data back

Comment: Did not notice the size update at the end in the function `writeToFrontOfPipe` ! Looks so simple once you know it.